# How do i put a comma next to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) <= 3:
    print ('Hi', name, ', you have a short name.') 
else:
    print('Hi', name, ', you have a long name.')
```

Comment: It looks like you already have a comma next to a variable.

Comment: When i run it, this is my answer: Enter your name: ian
Hi ian , you have a short name. and i want to move the comma back one space

Comment: Another option is to use the `sep` arg of `print`, eg  `print('Hi ', name, ', you have a short name.', sep='')`. And in Python 3.6+ you can use an f-string to do the formatting: `print(f'Hi {name}, you have a short name.')`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use format?

```
print("Hi {}, you have a short name".format(name))
```

Comment: Downvote with no reason, well

Comment: thanks for the help B

Comment: No problem, also, python's docs are good, you can always look there

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's always a risk when you answer questions that are fairly obvious duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the 'format' function:

```
print('Hey {name}, you have a nice name'.format(name=name))
```

Answer (score -2):

You could you the plus operator where-ever you don't need any space.